# Why diff is not working as expected?

Tags: linux, bash, comparison, diff

I have two files with a lot of paths and I want to compare them. But I don't know why it is not working with some of lines:
The same line is in the snapshot1 and snapshot2 and diff continues showing them, why?

```
root@minino:/tmp/diffshot# cat snapshot1|grep "MARCOS/lapiz.png"
-rw-r--r-- 1 minino minino 35247 may 19  2013 /home/minino/Imágenes/FONDOS/MARCOS/lapiz.png

root@minino:/tmp/diffshot# cat snapshot2|grep "MARCOS/lapiz.png"
-rw-r--r-- 1 minino minino 35247 may 19  2013 /home/minino/Imágenes/FONDOS/MARCOS/lapiz.png

root@minino:/tmp/diffshot# diff snapshot1 snapshot2 |grep "MARCOS/lapiz.png"
< -rw-r--r-- 1 minino minino 35247 may 19  2013 /home/minino/Imágenes/FONDOS/MARCOS/lapiz.png
> -rw-r--r-- 1 minino minino 35247 may 19  2013 /home/minino/Imágenes/FONDOS/MARCOS/lapiz.png
```

Comment: No, both are created in the same way. I can share the files, but they are very large files, 20Mb aprox.

Comment: Here they are: http://www.filedropper.com/snapshotstar

Comment: Maybe tabs in 1 and spaces in the other file? Or `\r\n` and `\n` ? Append `|od -cx` and see where you have a diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### try sorting first

`cat snapshot1 | sort | uniq > snapshot1sorted`

`cat snapshot2 | sort | uniq > snapshot2sorted`

`diff -w snapshot1sorted snapshot2sorted |grep "MARCOS/lapiz.png`

Comment: There isn't extra whitespaces in the lines. The result is the same.